# JS: Enlarge different pictures when clicked

Tags: javascript, python

I'm having trouble enlarging pictures on my web. I'm using JS and Python, below is my code.

*enlarge.js*

```
    var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    var contImg = document.getElementById('img01');
    var caption = document.getElementById('caption');

    var txtSpan = document.getElementById('txtSpan');
    img.onclick = function () {
        // console.log('111');
        modal.style.display = 'block';
        contImg.src = img.src
        caption.innerHTML = img.alt
    }
    var closeBox = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];
    closeBox.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }
```

*enlarge.html*

```
{% for img in imgs %}
        <img id="myImg" alt="detail" src="/static/img/problemPictures/{{img.name}}" />
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
            <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>
            <img class="modal-content" id="img01" src="">
            <div id="caption"></div>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

*views.py*

```
def test_problem_detail(request):
    if(request.method=='GET'):
        problemId=request.GET.get('problemId')
        problem=TestProblem.objects.get(id=problemId)
        imgs=TestProblem.objects.get(id=problemId).testproblempicture_set.all()
        comments = TestProblem.objects.get(id=problemId).testproblemcomment_set.all()
        return render(request, 'lab_management/test_problem_detail.html',
                  {'problem': problem, 'imgs': imgs, 'comments': comments})
```

This actually worked on the first picture. But if I have multiple pictures, the others won't enlarge if I click them. How can I make this work? Thank you in advance!

Comment: all your images have the same ID `myImg` - but `document.getElementById('myImg')` gives only first object with this ID. And it assigns function only to first image. You should use unique IDs - ie. `myImg1` ,`myImg2`, etc. or you should use class and `document.getElementsByClass()` (with char `s` in word `Elements`). BTW: and inside function you should try to use `this` instead of `img`

Comment: and the same problem is with another `getElementById`. You should rather find all images, (using class), and inside function search other elements using relative functions - `img.getElements...` instead of `document.getElements...`

Comment: if you solved it then you could put solution (with description) as answer - and later you can mark it as accepted. Answer can be useful for other people. And accepted answer will show that problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

*enlarge.html*

```
{% for img in imgs %}
{# keypoint:Replace all the original elements marked with id with classname, and getElementsByClassName in js code #}
        <img class="myImg" alt="detail" src="/static/img/problemPictures/{{img.name}}" />
        <div class="myModal modal" >
            <span class="close" >&times;</span>
            <img class="modal-content img01"  src="">
            <div class="caption" style="text-align: center"></div>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

*enlarge.js*

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('myImg');
var modals= document.getElementsByClassName('myModal');
var contImgs = document.getElementsByClassName('img01');
var captions = document.getElementsByClassName('caption');

/* This is the keypoint: Put the related operations of zooming in on the image 
into a loop, then get each image element in turn to complete the zoom operation */
for (let i = 0; i <imgs.length ; i++) {
    console.log('imgs.length'+imgs.length);
    var img=imgs[i];
    var modal=modals[i];
    var contImg=contImgs[i];
    var caption=captions[i];
    img.onclick = function () {
        console.log('111');
        modal.style.display = 'block';
        contImg.src = img.src
        console.log(contImg.src,'srccc');
        caption.innerHTML = img.alt
    }
    var closeBox = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[i];
    closeBox.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```